# Lightbox using tags or <a href=[base64]>

Tags: javascript, base64, lightbox

Is there any lightbox implementation that allows using `<a href=base64-string"` instead of an actual url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think you can use [Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2). It has it's own [LinkMapper function](http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/wiki/jQueryAPI#The_linkMapper_function). This allows you to return any url you want, based on element you are working on at that moment. This is javascript, so you could do an ajax request or whatever kind of link you want to return.

So yes, you need jQuery for this one, but I think there is a Mootools version as well. Have a look at it.

Comment: Didn't try this one but checked out the docs and it looks like this is another good option, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You only tagged javascript, however if you can use jQuery you could use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to achieve this with little work:

```
$("a[href^='data:image']").each(function(){
    $(this).fancybox({
        content: $("<img/>").attr("src", this.href)
    });
});
```

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/mmMVN/1/)

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for!

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 still has issues with this when the url is longer, but this is an ie limitation, works great in chrome though.

Answer (score 2):

To me works replacing the `href` with `data-remote` as follow,

```
<a data-remote="{{ base64string }}" data-gallery="multiimages" data-toggle="lightbox">
    <img src="{{ base64string }}" />
</a>
```

Comment: in my situation it worked without replacing the href. I did need to add the data-gallery and data-toggle attributes resulting in: <a href="{{ base64string }}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="{{ something_here }}" data-lightbox="{{ something_here }}"><img src="{{ base64string }}" /></a>