# Convert img tag to an 'a' tag to work with light box

Tags: html, lightbox

So I am trying to use the   [LightBox plugin](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9#getting-started). However I am querying my mysql database and displaying it with a img tag. But it seems to me that LightBox requires an 'a' tag. Does anyone know how to do so?

```
echo '<img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" />';
```

I have tried:

```
echo '<a id="database" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" />';
```

but nothing shows up if I do this. Otherwise using the img tag, everything displays fine.

Additional info: If it helps I am storing the images as a blob on a mysql database.
Thank you

**Update 1:**

```
echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'"  data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /><a/>';
```

This image now links to itself upon which is great! But still isn't right for Lightbox functionality. How I set up lightbox as par instructions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<script src="/var/www/html/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>


<title>Greeting Cards</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/lightbox2-master/dist/css/lightbox.css">

</head>

<body>

<!--------Logo------------>
<div id="logo">
<a href="../../index.html" >
<img src="../../icon/icon.png" alt="Our logo picture" >
</a>
</div>
<!------------------------>

<h2>Greeting Cards</h2>

 <!-------->
<?php
 /* Getting the blobs from mysql database */

echo '<div id ="gallery">';

foreach ($images as $image) {
  $image = WideImage::loadFromString($image)->resize(300, 300); //image resizing here

  echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'"  data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /><a/>'; 
}
echo '</div>';

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<script src="/var/www/lightbox2-master/dist/js/lightbox.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo '<a  href=""#><img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /><a/>'; try this

Comment: Oh that worked! The image is now a link! However, upon clicking on the image, the image opens the image on the same tab with just the picture.

Comment: Or maybe I don't have lightbox properly set up, but I have double checked and it looks right as from tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox does not have support for base64-strings in the href-tag it seems. There are some suggestions using data-remote in this thread here: [Lightbox using tags or <a href=[base64]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614608/lightbox-using-tags-or-a-href-base64)

Other than that there are other alternatives such as Fancybox, this can be found here:
http://fancybox.net

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check out other alternatives on the thread. I think you are right. Thanks to Mike Phils' comment the images are now a link, BUT upon clicking on the images, the images open on the same tab to display it.

Comment: Or maybe I don't have lightbox properly set up, but I have double checked and it looks right as from tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<a href=""#><img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /><a/>';` 
Credit to Mike Phils.

This worked! And don't forget to link all your plugin files correctly! Hope this helps someone.